# Can't get exception's message in Django custom validator

Tags: python, django, validation

I'm writing a custom validator that receives a list of validators, and checks if any of them passes, so you can easily check for things like *this integer field should be lower than 10 or higher than 100*. This is what I have so far:

```
class ValidateAnyOf(object):
    def __init__(self, *validators):
        self.validators = validators

    def __call__(self, value):
        errors = []
        for validator in self.validators:
            try:
                validator(value)
                return
            except ValidationError as e:
                errors.append(e.message)

        raise ValidationError('Combined validation failed:' + ','.join(errors))

class TestModel(models.Model):
    score = models.IntegerField(validators=[ValidateAnyOf(validators.MaxValueValidator(10),
                                                          validators.MinValueValidator(100))])
```

The logic is ok. The problem arises when none of the validators passes. I want to show a list of the errors, so I store in a list the messages from the exceptions. The problem is that `e.message` seems to be a `django.utils.functional.__proxy__` object, instead of a string, so I can't join them to show the full error message.

How can I get the error message from each exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are an instance of `django.utils.functional.__proxy__` because the `message` of the Django core validators is translatable and wrapped in `ugettext_lazy`. I think you can use something like `", ".join(unicode(e) for e in errors)` to force evaluation of the message.

Comment: `unicode(e.message)` did the trick. I had to manually pass the params for the placeholders using `errors.append(unicode(e.message) % e.params)` and it worked.

Comment: You can also now use django.utils.encoding.force_text instead of unicode.